# Generic class as Parameter

Tags: swift, generics

I was trying to use generics to get away with a lot of casting. I will provide a simple example:

```
import UIKit

class List<T> {
    let items: [T]

    init(items: [T]) {
        self.items = items
    }
}

class ListsViewController: UIViewController {
     var lists: [List<AnyObject>] = []
}

let viewController = ListsViewController()
let lists = [List(items: ["Fruits"])]
viewController.lists = lists
                       ^ error "String" is not identical to "AnyObject"
```

I've read that i could do

```
class ListsViewController<T>: UIViewController
```

but than i would have the problem further down the chain where i have to save ListsViewController instances...so that doesn't help.

What i don't get here why does the example work with the default Swift Arrays:

```
import UIKit

class ListsViewController: UIViewController {
     var lists: [AnyObject] = []
}

let viewController = ListsViewController()
let lists = ["Fruits", "Meat"]
viewController.lists = lists
```

No error although lists is of type [String] not [AnyObject]. Can i get the same behaviour for my generic class as well?

Thanks so much for your help in advance!

Comment: Here's an article about contravariance and covariance that might help a bit. http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/type-variance-in-swift Many languages allow arrays to be covariant (even though it's not type safe and requires a run time check). However this "leniency" is not always applied to all classes as you've discovered. C# has this same issue (well it did until it added a type safe way to implement covariance)

Comment: Here's a short relevant paragraph from the link I posted "All that said, can we developers declare types to be covariant, contravariant, or invariant? Not that I can see. So far, the default is that built-in variance rules work (arrays and dictionaries covariant, functions are…whatever they are, etc.), but custom types are all invariant."

Comment: i see, well too bad :(
thanks for sorting it out though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 8/22/2016:** As @DeFrenZ pointed out in the comments, my example relies on collections being reference types. However, in Swift, collections are value types. So *if* you could compile my example, I don't think there would be any issues. The variables `lists` and `lists2` are separate collections. Mutating one will not affect the other.

Original post continues below:

In addition to my comments above and the link I shared http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/type-variance-in-swift (by Alexandros Salazar) it's worth pointing out why covariance of collections (with no constraints) is generally not type safe.

Here's an example:

```
var lists: [List<AnyObject>] = []
var lists2: [List<String>] = List(items: ["Fruits"])
lists = lists2            // lists is now an alias for lists2 and is a reference to a list of strings
lists.append(MyObject())  // Now I just put a MyObject into a list of strings
var str:String = lists2[1] // assuming the previous lines compiled and ran ok, this would be a problem because lists2[1] is a MyObject.
```

(I'm writing this syntax from memory and don't recall Swift's actual semantics when assigning collections to variables, but hopefully this points out the issue.)

Comment: This is really important. The failure here isn't that Swift is lacking features, but that what you're asking for is not correct.  What you really need to do is to add a type parameter on `ListsViewController` so you have `lists:[T]` rather than `lists: [AnyObject]`. Almost any time you find yourself using `AnyObject` in a property, you are probably doing something incorrect. You should dig into why this is causing trouble with saving. That's probably fixable.

Comment: Good point @RobNapier. Probably more important than my comments on covariance on helping him with his problem.

Comment: Thanks for all your explanations. That's true, after thinking about it I will refactor my class to not use AnyObject after all. I'm no Language pro, but in my opinion it should still be allowed to put a subclass of a defined superclass into a collection and just move on from there. In your example "lists" would then become [List<String>] so lists.append(MyObject()) would fail. But that's just me :)

Comment: @warly that's precisely what happens with arrays. The down-side is two-fold: 1) This is potentially unsafe (as shown) and the compiler says nothing, 2) There is a runtime cost to checking every entry into the array to make sure its the right type. (I wouldn't be surprised if future versions of Swift allow covariance with some constraints. For example, covariance of collections if they are immutable is perfectly safe.)

Comment: Isn't that example snippet assuming that `Array` is a reference type? Because they are value types, and the assignment `lists = lists2` won't keep a reference but just copy the contents. Of course there is another issue, which is that `String is AnyObject == false`. It's `NSString is AnyObject == true`.

Comment: @DeFrenZ I believe you are correct. At the time I wrote that I perhaps did not know or hadn't yet "internalized" that collections were value types in Swift.